# What's the largest a canine could realistically get?

Tags: science-based, biology, creature-design, evolution

Giant dogs aren't uncommon in works of fantasy. Sif from Dark Souls comes to mind.

[image]

What I want to know is: what's the largest a canine could realistically get, what differences would they need compared to regular dogs in order to function, and what evolutionary pressures would lead a group of canids to evolve to such large sizes?

Note: Magic does not exist in my story.

Comment: An animal the size of Paraceratherium cannot run or jump. It makes sense for an herbivore, it makes no sense for a carnivore who is supposed to run after its lunch.

Comment: wasn't T-rex also that large but still a carnivore?

Comment: it wasn't a mammal, and wasn't chasing other mammals.

Comment: I think the dog's size is fine but the proportion needs fine adjustment, neck could be a bit thicker and need more practices on it's swordmanship too predictable and I could solo it colorblinded anytime. ;p

Comment: Is your story intended for a visual medium? Film, animation, comics? Because in a written story I don't see why you would need anything other than "humongous wolf".

Comment: @AlexP i'm hoping i can get my story animated

Comment: And since when do animated movies represent *any* animal faithfully?

Comment: @AlexP i'm trying to go for "scientifically accurate fantasy" where it's fanatical but still obeys biology and the laws of physics. that's is the main through line with this account

Comment: Well then, canids and ursids are closely related (the are both branches of the clade [Caniformia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caniformia)). Among the bears, male cave bears ([*Ursus spelaeus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cave_bear)) reached about a ton in weight, which seems to be near the top of the reasonable range for a land mammalian carnivore. Skeletons of cave bears are so common that once upon a time they were *mined* as a source of phosphate.

Comment: @AlexP maybe i should make the question about "whats the largest a canine could realistically get?" then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106185/discussion-between-icewar1908-and-alexp).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The largest terrestrial mammalian predator by weight was Andrewsarchus:

[image]

You can get a little more height using a slighter build like Daeodon here:

[image]

But that is about your limit. Mammals are really poorly designed for large size, our bones, skeletal structure and respiratory system are just garbage if you are trying to be big. Dinosaurs get huge because they have hollow bones, a massively reinforced pelvic girdle, and no lumbar region.